# Meteor - Order in which WebApp.connectHandlers.use() is evaluated

Tags: meteor

How can I make my rules in WebApp.connectHandlers.use() be evaluated before the native meteor rules?

I want to prevent certain files in **/imports@...** from being delivered depending on the source of the request.

Ex:

```js
/imports/@/bulica.local/index.js;
/imports/@/caneco.local/index.js;
/imports/@/192.168.0.1/index.js;
```

and in **/server/index.js** in the first instructions:

```js
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/imports/@/', (req, res, next) => {
  //  compare
  //  req._parsedUrl.pathname with req.headers['x-forwarded-server'] 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

In Meteor there is another instance of connect that is not in the documentation that is processed before the code created by the developer.

It's WebAppInternals.

So just replace

**WebApp**`.connectHandlers.use ...`

per

**WebAppInternals**`.connectHandlers.use ...`

Otherwise it's the same